# RecyclerView with a 2 column-per-row, then 1 column-per-row pattern

Tags: android

I am trying to create a RecyclerView layout with a CardView with the following pattern:

[image]

In the above image, each square/rectangle will be a CardView.

I have tried various approaches, including creating two different CardView Layouts, where one is a full-width CardView and where the other includes two CardViews, with different IDs.

However, when the viewholder tries to bind more layouts then there actually are, since one layout file includes two child layouts (2 card views).

Is there a library that can handle this? I also tried the [SpannedGridLayout library](https://github.com/Arasthel/SpannedGridLayoutManager), but there is a glitch where if you scroll beyond the first page, it crashes.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to use your custom Layout Manager, since there is no Layout Manager in the ADK that does what you need. Take a look here for a great example on how to do it:

http://blog.sqisland.com/2014/12/recyclerview-grid-with-header.html

Comment: Thanks, seems like exactly what I am looking for!

Comment: TL;DR use ```gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(..)``` https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/GridLayoutManager#setSpanSizeLookup(androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using RecyclerView with GridLayoutManager

```
TourEnum[] values = TourEnum.values();
```

create List and set Adapter

```
prepareList();

adapter = new MyAdapter(context, list);

GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 8);
            gridLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
                @Override
                public int getSpanSize(int position) {
                    int pos = values[position % 8].points;
                    return pos;
                }

            });

 recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
```

Pattern will be created using Enum classes

```
public enum TourEnum {

        ONE(4),
        TWO(4),
        THREE(8),
        FOUR(4),
        FIVE(4),
        SIX(8),
        SEVEN(4),
        EIGHT(4);

    //points determines amount of points each card is worth in Gin Rummy
    public final int points;

    //standard Rank constructor
    TourEnum(int points) {
        this.points = points;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can create adapter class like this for different views

```
public class SampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
public Context context;
private ArrayList<String> stringArrayList;

public SampleAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

public SampleAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> stringlist) {
    this.stringArrayList = stringlist;
    this.context = context;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View root;
    switch (viewType) {
        case 1:
            root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first_view, parent, false);
            return new SecondViewHolder(root, viewType);

        case 2:
            root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.second_view, parent, false);
            return new FirstViewHolder(root, viewType, context);
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {


}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position % 2 == 0) {
        return 1;

    } else {
        return 2;
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return stringArrayList.size();
}


public static class FirstViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public FirstViewHolder(View itemView, int viewType, Context context) {
        super(itemView);

    }
}

public static class SecondViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public SecondViewHolder(View itemView, int viewType) {
        super(itemView);

    }
}
}
```

and `first_view.xml` will be the single item xml like this:

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp">


<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/buttonRecordingNormal1"
        android:layout_height="100dp">
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

you can set cardview inside this xml according to your need
        and `second_view.xml` will be like this which contain two views :

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/buttonFocused2"></LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/buttonRecordingNormal2"></LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

then final in your activity,

```
  recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recylerView);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

        ArrayList<String>list=new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0 ;i <15; i ++)
        {
        list.add("");

        }
        sampleAdapter = new SampleAdapter(getActivity(), list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(sampleAdapter);
```

you can pass anything like bean object list etc. i am passing simple string list for showing view and approx 15 items.